# Webpack unable to find babel-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm having a bit of trouble adding react to a legacy application. While I found plenty of materials on getting started, I ran into a bunch of issues related to my particular configuration and exacerbated by my utter lack of webpack knowledge (so much time relying on react cli tools makes one lax).

My configuration:

- `./docs/jslib` = my node_modules, that's where yarn installs modules
- `./docs/jscripts` = my general js folder, various js scripts go there
- `./docs/jscripts/mini` = my dist folder, some things get built/packed by gulp and end up here. This is where the built things are expected to go
- `./docs/jscripts/react(/react.js)` = my desired root for react things, where the react.js is the entrypoint for DOM selection and rendering (at least for the first attempt).

My webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./docs/jscript/react/react.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./docs/jscript/mini"),
        filename: "react.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "./docs/jslib")
        ],
        alias: {
            'babel-loader': path.resolve(__dirname, "./docs/jslib/babel-loader")
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "./docs/jscript/react")
                ],
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "./docs/jslib")
                ],
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

The error I get on running webpack:

```sh
yarn run v1.21.1
$ ./docs/jslib/babel-loader/node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production

Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

Hash: 210250af48f3cf84fa4a
Version: webpack 4.41.6
Time: 75ms
Built at: 02/14/2020 9:23:09 AM

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/var/www/html'
```

I have webpack-cli, I can run webpack straight, I can run it from the modules bin folder, it's all the same problem - it can't find babel-loader even though babel-loader brings its own webpack script which I use, so the loader is obviously there in the "node_modules" that's actually on a different path.

From what I gathered, all I had to do was to add my custom node_modules path to the webpack config under the `resolve` settings, which has solved my initial errors related to packages not found (yet webpack still can't find the loader).

Note: if I symlink my ./docs/jslib as ./node_modules, it works as expected.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the node_modules directory?

Comment: @tmdesigned thanks for the suggest, I did. However, the directory holding the modules isn't "node_modules" in the default location but has a different location and name. If I symlink it as node_modules in the expected location, all works as expected (but that's not a viable solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found a solution and some details that other might want to keep in mind when configuring webpack in a rather non-standard context:

- resolve: points to modules that are directly required in various scripts
- resolveLoader: should point to the same, for the purpose of accessing loaders (which is what I needed)

Solution:

```
    resolveLoader: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx'],
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "./docs/jslib")
        ],
        mainFields: ['loader', 'main']
    }
```